# How can I show function's parameter's values in output in sql server management?

Tags: sql-server, debugging, output, ssms

I write a very long Table-Value function in sql server management.
I have parameters, and I want to their values while running. (Because it's running a very long time, and has problems. I want to fix it).
Is it possible to show this output in a console or something like?
Thanks.

Comment: You *could* however, this would change the function from a inline table-value function (I assume that's the type you've used) to a multi-line table-value function. The latter perform far more slowly that the former, so you would likely be better debugging outside of the function, not inside.

Comment: In truth, if the function is running slowly, this likely means it's poorly written, or the database is poorly designed. Instead of trying to find out the values you're using, you would be better working out why it's slow. Poor join predicates, non-SARGable clauses, using a milti-line table-value function, will all be causes for slow performance. If you post the DDL of your function, we may well be able to see some quick wins on making your function faster.

Comment: @Larnu. It's running slow because it works with a huge DB. My problem is not because of it, I just want to see the parameters values.

Comment: A huge DB can still run quickly, if it's well designed @utor . if your function is slow, it is far more likely to point at the design than the volume of data. That, or your server is (severely) under resourced.

Comment: Have a look at `RAISERROR` and the option `WITH NOWAIT`.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. In SSMS there is an option to "Include query in the result set". If you check it, it will print in Message tab your query and that include your parameters.